# segmentation fault - socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I'm having a problem with running a small block of code. This is regarding socket programming in C. What I'm trying to do is have a client communicate to a server on two different ports. But when i'm trying to compile the client code, i get 'segmentation fault'. I'm giving my client code here. Please let me know what's going wrong.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdbool.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
     int sockfd,newsockfd,sockfd_infinite,sockfd_kitchen,portno,portno1,n,no_of_tables;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,kitchen_addr;
     struct hostent *server,*kitchen;
     struct timeval time_out;
     time_out.tv_sec = 15;    // 15 seconds
     time_out.tv_usec = 0;    // 0 milliseconds
    //       server=gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    //       char buffer[256];
     portno=atoi(argv[2]);
     portno1=atoi(argv[4]);
     sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
     if(sockfd==-1)
            error("\nError creating socket");
     server=gethostbyname(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);
     bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
            (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            server->h_length);

     sockfd_kitchen=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
     if(sockfd_kitchen==-1)
            error("\nError creating socket");
     kitchen=gethostbyname(argv[3]);
     kitchen_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
     kitchen_addr.sin_port=htons(portno1);
     bcopy((char *)kitchen->h_addr,
            (char *)&kitchen_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            kitchen->h_length);

     n=connect(sockfd_kitchen,(struct sockaddr *)&kitchen_addr,sizeof(kitchen_addr));
     if(n==-1)
            error("\nError connecting to kitchen");
     n=connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
     if(n==-1)
            error("\nError connecting to server");
     return 0;
    }
```

So the idea behind this code is - there is a client and there is a server. This client wants to communicate with the server on two different ports as if the client is talking to two different servers. I'm doing this on my laptop giving in the server names as 'localhost' for both the server names and different port numbers. Like you see in my code, I have two pointer variables for the two servers namely, *server and *kitchen.

Eg:
./thiscode localhost 15535 localhost 12345

In the example I've mentioned, this is how I'm compiling my client code. argv[1] is the first "localhost" (server name) and argv[2] is the port number of the first server. The second "localhost" and '12345' are the second server's name and port number.

Like I've said before, I'm trying to have three windows on my laptop running three different codes (one for client and two for servers). My two server codes compile without any problem but my client code gets this 'segmentation' fault. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Short of a bug in your compiler, you are _not_ getting a SEGV when you compile. You're getting it when you run. There, I've reached my pedantry quota for the day :-)

Comment: Your first reaction as a programmer when you get a crash in your program, segmentation fault or any other, should be to run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate the place of the crash, as well as let you examine variables to help you figure out the cause of the crash.

Comment: A few comments: (1) Your code doesn't check argc before using argv, so if you run to program with no arguments then you'll overflow there. (2) Even if the correct number of arguments are given, you should check that they're parsed correctly. (3) valgrind gives tons of output when running this code, so you should follow Joachim's advice.

Comment: what does your debugger say about this?

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you should be checking the return values from `gethostbyname`:

> The gethostbyname() and gethostbyaddr() functions return the hostent structure or a NULL pointer if an error  occurs. On  error, the h_errno variable holds an error number.

Comment: I did check with h_errno with HOST_NOT_FOUND value. For a normal server-client socket programming in C, even though h_errno equals HOST_NOT_FOUND, i can still have data being transferred between server and client. I'm not clear how this is happening!

Comment: @Richard, `h_errno` (just like `errno`) is irrelevant _unless the return value has indicated an error._ Otherwise, it could be set to _any_ value. In other words, check if the function returns NULL, and only if it does, then look at `h_errno`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in `bcopy()` function call.

**You have not declared space for the variable before copying stuff into it, and hence you saw a segmentation fault**.

Enter the following code before the `bcopy()` statement to remove the Seg-fault:

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
```